# Can you make word2vec use left context and right context separately?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am using word2vec through gensim currently.  You can set the context size easily (that sets the number of words to the left and right of a center word to consider).  Sometimes it's better to consider the words to the left separately to the words to the the right. This would give two embeddings per word.

Can this be done in gensim or in any other python compatible tool?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a built-in feature, and the code that practically the window is deep in its Cython- optimized routines. But, as all the code is open-source, you could modify it to do so.

For example, source for the current `gensim-3.8.3` release's calculation of the window start `j` & window end `k` positions for skip-gram mode is viewable at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/release-3.8.3/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx#L574

Also modifying the model to keep two vectors for every token-key, and offer user lookup for those tokens, & adapt the other model operations for working on both, would require changes elsewhere, too.

Comment: This is a shame. Is there any other software that is easier to configure for this?

Comment: None that I know of - and I haven't seen any word2vec implementation that offers imbalanced/one-sided context-windows.  I suspect it's been tried before and didn't offer compelling benefits for the usual word2vec applications, as I've not seen any demos/papers touting one-sided windows. There was once a request/contribution to gensim allowing one-sided (left-only) windows  – and the author said that had a benefit for their specific use – but even that (never-integrated) feature didn't offer separate word-vectors for the same word for both left- and right- contexts.

Comment: That's very interesting. It is explicitly recommend in http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/

Comment: Do you have a more specific link to the exact text/context/lecture where that's recommended?

Comment: I will look that up as soon as I can.